# Disable ignoring *everything*

Tags: feature-request, ignored-tags

Apparently if I add `*` to my ignored list it ignores **everything**.

I know it is trivial and probably will never happen, but can we disable adding `*` to the ignore or favorite tag lists?

Comment: Why? From time to time people come here thinking they spend too much time on the SE network and asking for features to help them "kick back the habit". This is such a feature.

Comment: But what if I *wanted* to ignore everything? What then?! :-P

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Then you disable your network connection.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Garbage In Garbage Out.*

If you do stupid things stupid things may actually happen. I'd say it'd be a waste of developer time to prevent that.

Comment: Again, as I said: _trivial_

Comment: You did *ask*...